# Wrap a word if no space

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
   <h6 class="text-center" 
    style="white-space: pre-line; word-break: keep-all;">
    <strong>Bill Date: </strong> {{billSummaryObj.bill_date || '--'}}
   </h6>
```

The date breaks after hyphen. After -hyphen, the remaining part of date goes to next line. How to make whole date go to next line

Comment: could you please add an image of the text you wanted?

Comment: add a working example code like CSS & HTML, what you want & what is the problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<wbr>` after your `</strong>` which is a break that only occurs when it's needed.

I'm not sure if `white-space` or `word-break` interfers with how `<wbr>` works so you might have to turn those off for it to work.

Comment: you means <br/>

Comment: `<wbr>` is legit. Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr It breaks a word when it's *needed*

Comment: It is only  legit and valid when html 5 is used as only html 5 defined it to make one thing clear..

Answer (score 0):

Use a `span` tag for the date and use css Flex for `h6`.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* you may not need this */

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h6 class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center w-100">
  <strong> Bill Date: </strong>
  <span>{{billSummaryObj.bill_date || '--'}}</span>
</h6>
```

If you want to have the date on its own line  irrespective of the available space, give  `<strong>`  a `100%` width.